# Статические члены класса vs статические переменные метода

Tags: c++

Есть пример кода (рабочий):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

class T1
{
public:
    static double random_value() {
        static unsigned seed = chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
        static default_random_engine rg(seed);
        static normal_distribution<double> rnd(1.0, .1);
        return rnd(rg);
    }
};

class T2
{
public:
    double random_value() {
        return rnd(rg);
    }

private:
    static const unsigned seed;
    static default_random_engine rg;
    static normal_distribution<double> rnd;
};

int main()
{
    T1 t1; T2 t2;
    for (int i=0; i<30; ++i) {
        cout << t1.random_value() << " " << t2.random_value() << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

const unsigned T2::seed = chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
default_random_engine T2::rg(T2::seed);
normal_distribution<double> T2::rnd(1.0, .1);
```

В итоге, для класса Т1 нужна будет нестатическая функция, использующая `random_value`. Какая реализация (T1 или Т2) предпочтительнее?

Comment: если работает - то без разницы

Comment: @YuriyOrlov, да, работает вроде одинаково корректно. Я с точки зрения высокого штиля...

Answer (score 1):

Все статические объекты в `T1` создаются при первом вызове `random_value`, статические члены в `T2` создаются до начала работы функции `main`. Больше никакой разницы нет. Предпочтительнее не использовать глобальное состояние вообще, как уже сказал Вам [@Abyx](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/499585/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-vs-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0#comment594886_499585).

Из двух предложенных Вами вариантов можно выбирать любой, разницы Вы не заметите.

Comment: Интересно, как можно использовать ГПСЧ без глобального состояния генератора? Ну, можно его по всей цепочке параметром пихать, но надо ли это? Генератор случайных чисел, ИМХО, и должен по сути своей быть глобальным. Многопоточность (пока) не беспокоит.

Comment: @andy.37, генератор для каждой сущности может быть свой. Зачем один на всех?

Comment: А в чем смысл создавать свой генератор для нескольких тысяч объектов? Да и инициализация будет происходить пракически одновременно, тогда нужно `seed` как-то специально модифицировать.

Comment: @andy.37, я выразил мнение, мне не известны параметры Вашей системы, поэтому от дальнейших комментариев воздержусь.